# PHP script is duplicating Joomla! module content

Tags: php, joomla, module, duplicates

I have found a small script that I have used within a Joomla template to check and see if there is a module assigned to a particular module position on the current page.

```
    <?php   
        $attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
        $modules_html = '';
        foreach (JModuleHelper::getModules( 'module_position' ) as $module)
            $modules_html .= JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs );
        $show_module=trim($modules_html) != '';
        if ($show_module) {                         
    ?>

    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="module_position" style="xhtml" />

    <?php } ?>
```

The script works well but duplicates the module wrapper div and the title so the output is generally as follows:

```
<div class="moduletable">
    <h3>Module Title</h3>
    <div class="moduletable">
        <h3>Module Title</h3>
        <p>Content here</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get rid of the duplicate wrapper and title but cannot figure out for the life of me how to do so.

Suggestions would be most welcome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you are putting jdoc tag in loop so it will get repeated if you have multiple modules published on same position.

you need to have it just once.
you can also use countModules function of joomla. See here http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/countModules